# Java reflection invoking main method of jar sometimes throws ClassNotFoundException?

Tags: java, reflection, classloader, program-entry-point, classnotfoundexception

I'm invoking another jar file using reflection like this `mainMethod.invoke(null, new Object[] { passargs });` (basic stuff). It works for most jar files, but for one I keep getting a `ClassNotFoundException`. It's erroring out on the first line of code in the external jar which is creating a new object defined in that jar (although the other classes load their own jar-classes fine). Since the error is occuring on the first line of the jar's main method, I don't think it's using any custom classloaders.

Any ideas what could cause a ClassNotFoundException when calling the main method of another jar? **This works for many other complex jars. Just one of them isn't working, and I'm wondering what could be the cause. It works fine when I executed it individually with `java -jar`**

```
//my jar
JarFile jar = new JarFile(load);
Attributes attributes = jar.getManifest().getMainAttributes();
String mainClass = attributes.getValue("Main-Class");

URLClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] { new File(load).toURI().toURL() }, ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
Class main = cl.loadClass(mainClass);
System.out.println("MAIN CLASS: " + mainClass);
Method mainMethod = main.getDeclaredMethod("main", new Class[] { String[].class });
mainMethod.invoke(null, new Object[] { new String[0] });
```

It throws the exception on this line
(Other jar - one being invoked)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    LoadingScreen ls = new LoadingScreen();
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/spoutcraft/launcher/gui/LoadingScreen
at org.spoutcraft.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:106)
at com.mineshaftersquared.MineshafterSquaredGUI.wrapJar(Driver.java:110)
at com.mineshaftersquared.resources.ServerProxy.main(ServerProxy.java:71)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.spoutcraft.launcher.gui.LoadingScreen
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
... 3 more
```

Comment: What class does the `ClassNotFoundException` talk about? (My guess is that it *is* a class that the entry point class refers to...)

Comment: @JonSkeet Holy crap it's John Skeet! Anyways - it points to another class in the other jar file (when I run the other jar standalone it works fine). In Eclipse, if I attach it to my build path, and call it without reflection I get the same error.

Comment: "The other jar file"? The same one you're invoking, or a different one? How are you making the class available anyway? A short but complete program demonstrating the problem would really help.

Comment: Other jar file = the one I'm invoking. I added my script, but there's not much other code useful (it craps out on the first line)

Comment: Are you dynamically loading the Jar file? It could be that it's missing a dependency that's not loaded in the class loader

Comment: @MadProgrammer the jar file works if I double click it from the same location, so I don't think it has any special classloaders. I'm wondering if the classloader I am using to load the jar is causing a problem, although it works with many other jars

Comment: @Raekye But you're loading the class into its own class loader. If that Jar relies on other Jars, they might not be loaded and made available within the class loader context. Can you post the exception as well?

Comment: @MadProgrammer posted the exception. Don't know how that works, but sounds like something I was suspecting. When I load a class using a custom classloader, does it inherit my classloader? If so, how do I make it use it's own class loader? Though again, the error is on the first line executed, so could it still be using a special classloader?

Comment: Does the "other jar" define a classpath in its manifest?

Comment: @Henry nope - nothing in the dynamically-loaded-jar about classpaths, although the calling-class was launched with a classpath. This calling-class works with other jars though

Comment: You also need to load `LoadingScreen`...

Comment: @assylias I highly doubt it. I can load other jars - which use many other classes defined in the loaded-jar - and those work fine. If this is the problem - why do the others work? I'm no expert - but I added `cl.loadClass("org.spoutcraft.launcher.gui.LoadingScreen");` (the class that was erroring) and it still doesn't work (same problem)

Comment: @Raekye When you run the Other jar(the one being invoked) individually using `java -jar` Is it executing successfully?